# Construir matrices en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando crear una matriz cuyo tamaño depende del valor de unos parámetros que recibo. El problema esta en que me pide que la matriz debe tener unos valores constantes para definir su tamaño.

Ej:

```
int main(){
int tam1,tam2;
cin >> tam1 >> tam2;
int matriz[tam1][tam2];
return 0;
}
```

¿Cómo podría solventar el problema?

PD: La matriz tiene intención de ser 'ESTATICA' y no variar su tamaño a lo largo del tiempo.

Comment: Mas bien intentas crear una matriz dinamica, donde tu matriz es declarada primero y luego es asignado su tamaño?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El concepto estático, en programación, quiere decir que la vida del objeto está ligada a la vida de la aplicación. Es decir, que el objeto morirá cuando finalice la aplicación.

Por otro lado, en C++, los arrays de tamaño fijo son estructuras cuyo número de elementos es fijo, y viene determinado en **tiempo de compilación**:

```
int vector[25];
char cadenaTipoC[200];
```

Este es el tipo de estructura que estás intentando crear. El motivo de que no funcione es que, como he dicho, el tamaño de estos elementos de determina en tiempo de compilación... mientras que en tu caso el tamaño se determina en tiempo de ejecución (es un dato introducido por el usuario).

Así pues los requisitos te impiden usar este tipo de estructura, por lo que tienes que recurrir a otras alternativas:

Puedes, por ejemplo, con trabajar con un puntero doble. La desventaja en este caso es que la creación y la liberación son un poco más largas:

```
int tam1,tam2;
cin >> tam1 >> tam2;
int** matriz = new int*[tam1];
for( int i=0; i<tam1; i++ )
  matriz[i] = new int[tam2];

// ...

for( int i=0; i<tam1; i++ )
  delete[] matriz[i];
delete[] matriz;
```

Por supuesto, llegado el momento podrías encapsular esta lógica en una clase, simplificando el código final.

Ahora bien, dices que quieres crear una matriz estática, que como hemos dicho, para ello basta con que se mantenga viva durante toda la ejecución del programa.

Para conseguir esto puedes optar por crear una variable global:

```
// Variable global
static int ** matriz;

int main()
{
  // ...
}
```

Aunque no es la opción que yo recomendaría... casi es preferible crear una clase estática o un espacio de nombres que almacene este objeto (por legibilidad, control de acceso y esas cosas):

**Clase estática**

```
static class CosasEstaticas
{
  static int** matriz = nullptr;

public:
  static void InicializarMatriz(int filas, int columnas)
  {
    if( matriz == nullptr )
    {
      matriz = new int*[filas];
      for( int i=0; i<filas; i++ )
        matriz[i] = new int[columnas];
    }
  }

  static int** Matriz()
  {
    return matriz;
  }
};
```

**Espacio de nombres**

Cabecera:
    //CosasEstaticas.h
    namespace CosasEstaticas
    {
      static void InicializarMatriz(int filas, int columnas);
      static int** Matriz();
    }

Implementación:
    // CosasEstaticas.cpp
    namespace
    {
      int** matriz = nullptr;
    }

```
 void CosasEstaticas::InicializarMatriz(int filas, int columnas)
 {
   if( matriz == nullptr )
   {
     matriz = new int*[filas];
     for( int i=0; i<filas; i++ )
       matriz[i] = new int[columnas];
   }
 }

  int** CosasEstaticas::Matriz()
  {
    return matriz;
  }
```

Claro que también puedes pasarle el puntero a todas las funciones que lo necesiten, lo cual te da más control sobre quién accede al objeto:

```
void tratarMatriz(int**matriz);

int main()
{
  int**matriz;
  // inicializacion matriz
  // ...

  tratarMatriz(matriz);

  // ...
}
```